# Bayes Theorem -- is this correct?

Tags: self-study, bayesian

Here is a problem using Bayes Theorem
Am I doing this correctly? ..:

To detect a medical condition, patients are given 2 tests. 25% of the patients receive positive results
on both tests and 42% of the patients receive positive results on the first one. What percent of those
who have positive results on the first also had positive result on the second?

The answer I'm coming up with is 59.5% --> am I doing this correctly? 
I know it should not be too hard to solve but want to make sure I'm doing the right thing (by dividing 0.25/0.42)

Comment: Are your assuming independence? Doesn't sound like you need Bayes.

Comment: You are doing it correctly, but it has nothing to do with Bayes. It has to do with conditional probability (which is what you are calculating).